# How to write a loop for this case in R?

Tags: r, loops, integrated

I have a data base with 121 rows and like 10 columns. One of these columns corresponds to Station, another to depth and the rest to chemical variables (temperature, salinity, etc.). I want to calculate the integrated value of these chemical properties by station, using the function oce::integrateTrapezoid. It's my first time doing a loop, so i dont know how. Could you help me?

```
dA<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=121, ncol=3)
for (Station in unique(datos$Station))
{dA[Station, cd] <- integrateTrapezoid(cd, Profundidad..m., "cA")
  }
```

| Station | Depth | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 28 |
| 1 | 50 | 25 |
| 1 | 100 | 15 |
| 1 | 150 | 10 |
| 2 | 9 | 27 |
| 2 | 45 | 24 |
| 2 | 98 | 14 |
| 2 | 152 | 11 |
| 3 | 11 | 28.7 |
| 3 | 48 | 23 |
| 3 | 102 | 14 |
| 3 | 148 | 9 |

Comment: You probably don't need a loop but `by` (from `base`) or `group_by` (from `dplyr`). I am not sure about your code, where does that `cd` comes from? What result/error do you get?

Comment: Cd is a another variable, like temperature or salinity... I don't get any error....
For example, the integration that a I want, it should be done considering the temperature values ​​at 10 and 50 m, and then at 50 to 100 m, and then from 100 to 150m, for the station 1. But what I get from the code is, after doing the station 1, the next integrated temperature value is made with the value at​​ 150m from the first station and the value at 9 m from the second station.... that's why a i want to separete by group of stations.

Comment: So  you want to apply a function *incrementally* over the rows, by group? So for example if the function was just a sum, for `temp` you would expect 28, 53, 68, 78 for Station 1 and 27, 51,  65, 76 for station 2, and so on?